# Meaning of files with one require line and nothing else

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have a project written in Angular 2 in TypeScript compiled by `Webpack` by previous team with whom I have no means of contact. In this project a `chart.js` package is used throughout the app many times. But in each component it is not imported directly but rather imported via special "loader" component. For instance I have a `cars-list.component.ts` that imports file from the same directory called `cars-list.loader.ts`. This loader file consists of a single line that looks like this:

```
export const Chart = require('chart.js'); // tslint:disable-line
```

I do not understand why they didn't just import chart.js directly and made this file in the middle. They wrote a dozen of copies of this same file with this exact line, one for each component.

I would rather delete these loader files and import `chart.js` directly. But I want to first understand the meaning of it. Is there any common practice to do this kind of files? Can anyone guess what it's made for?

Comment: There is no objective reason for doing this. It could be anything from simple preference to some convoluted automation (e.g. a script that does something special with them). But frankly, I can't think of any good reason to have the same file multiple times when you could just have a single file and always import from the same one. They are the only ones that know why they did it like that and you won't get any answer on Stack Overflow.